# Как загружать данные по расписанию?

Tags: android-service, android, java

Пишу программку. В ней есть функция типа "Day tips". То есть, каждый день она выдает новое напоминание, которое парсится через jsoup с сайта. Хочу сделать так, чтобы после наступления нового дня программа при подключении к интернету сразу лезла в сеть и сохраняла данные. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `AlarmManager`. Получается,установите "сигнализацию"( которая будер срабатывать в указаный интервал, или в конкретный час) которой нужно будет сделать проверку на подключение к интернету, если доступно, то парсите и сохраняйте, куда угодно.

[Доки](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), [туториал](http://www.mobilab.ru/androiddev/androidalarmmanagertutorial.html),[и еще один](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/alarmservice.php)

p.s. `Для планирования операций, которые работают только на протяжении жизненного цикла вашего приложения, вместо механизма сигнализации лучше использовать класс Handler в сочетании с таймерами и потоками. Это позволит Android лучше контролировать системные ресурсы.`